# Facebook doesn't fetch information from password protected blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, authentication, seo

I've a wordpress blog that is password protected members only portal.. When I try to share the blog link, it doesn't fetch the title, image or description of the blog, rather it just show the login title. Nothing else..

This happen because I've this code in the functions file that direct to the main non-wp website.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in())
    wp_redirect('http://fxxx.com/?redirect_to=' . 
 $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

If this code is removed, it normally fetch all the information, including images..

Any solution for this? I didn't find any blogs about this on google..

Comment: Open graph tags?

Comment: I may need more information about that..

Comment: We need to see some tags, as that is how it's obtained. Are your tags put after you are succesfully logged in? Or, how does your content get displayed before and after you login. We can't tell much about content displayment if you don't show us what code is used to try obtaining your goal. Also as @dingo_d mentioned, look into Open Graph tags, as that is what Facebook listens to when searching for a title, image and description.

Comment: The Facebook scraper can be recognized by its User-Agent (details see Social Plugins FAQ.) You would need to modify the above check accordingly - so that is does only redirect, if the requesting client is not the Facebook scraper. You have to be aware though that then everyone who sends that same User-Agent header with their request would also be able to see those pages without logging in.

Comment: Content is visible only after login that's the reason I'm directing the non-logged in users to the login page..@CBroe had a valid point.. But I guess there is very little information on how to approach that way.

Comment: The following will be treated as a redirect by the crawler:
A HTTP redirect
A <link rel="canonical" href=".." /> tag
A <meta property="og:url" content=".." /> tag..... That's what it's written there..

Comment: Can you check what tags are showing here
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Or just provide password protectd page

Comment: @Ashkar The content in redirected page (i.e. login page) is visible.. Scraper is following the above code..